# How to add Unity TextMeshPro custom <link> with custom outline?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I tried to add custom tag that has glowing outline, for example

```
this is a <link="customoutline">test</link>
```

But I couldnt find any useful tutorial or thread about this one

I tried assigned value to material through

```
tmpComponent.textInfo.meshInfo[materialIndex].material.SetFloat(ShaderUtilities.ID_OutlineWidth, 1f)
```

But when I do that, the value on material also get changed and affects all text that using same material as the one I want to custom, which I would like to avoid.

Again, I expect to have a textmeshpro custom tag, that have glowing outline.
Thank

Comment: you have to create a new material for custom TextMeshPro from TextMeshPro Editor
and apply it to your custom TextMeshPro Text now you can customize this material as you like and other TextMeshPro Text will not be affected

Comment: @ZahidHussain Thx for the reply, but I want to only highlight certain words inside a link tag. When I reference/changed the material value with script, all texts that use that material would change too.